# Hi, Is there any automated tool for testing dynamic web pages in Adobe CQ5

Tags: adobe, aem, automated-tests

Is Selenium/Junit intergrable with CQ5? Please suggest some tools

Comment: What do you want to test in cq5? The app part or the pulished pages?

Comment: yes, the apps part(esp. components and its behaviour)

Comment: Hmmm you can use Selenium to perform this. Let me know if you require any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both Selenium and JUnit are options, among others.

Check out [CQ - Writing Server-side JUnit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545248/cq-writing-server-side-junit-tests/20552432#20552432) for options on unit testing with JUnit.

Selenium is also an option because Selenium testing is all about the browser.  It is agnostic of the backend, so the fact that your web pages are delivered via CQ5 doesn't matter to Selenium.

Also check out https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/testing/definingyourtestcases.html