# CQ - Writing Server-side JUnit tests

Tags: unit-testing, osgi, aem, sling

I've been trying to write a JUnit test case for one of my Java class which creates a page with some given properties in CQ. For it, it need to get reference of SlingRepository and ResourceResolverFactory.  I was using [this](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/sling-testing-tools.html#server-side-junit-tests-contributed-by-bundles) to get an idea on how to achieve this. In the document it says that a POST to "http://$HOST:$PORT/system/sling/junit/" path is used to execute tests on server side. But in CQ I get a 404 error for this path.

Is there any alternative URL in CQ for this? Or will really appreciate if anyone can suggest a better approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to use a Sling test runner to execute the JUnit tests via a browser.  This is the approach you are mentioning.  We had to first install the code in this JAR ([org.apache.sling.junit.core](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Corg.apache.sling.junit.core)) to add the code that allows the URL you listed to work.  Once that code is there, this URL will allow you to run tests using the test runner's built in page to run/display tests: `http://localhost:4502/system/sling/junit/`).  My team did this for a while, but we soon moved to a different approach--using the Intellij IDE to develop the Java code for CQ and write the JUnit tests, then executing them within the IDE using the built-in JUnit test runner.  The same approach works in Eclipse.  For our team this approach was superior because it allowed developers to remain in context in the IDE without having to switch to a browser to run the tests.

The key is being able to resolve the references to classes that are installed/available via CQ, such as the SlingRepository and ResourceResolverFactory classes--and other stuff we commonly used, such as the Resource, ResourceResolver, Node, and Session classes.  We use a CQ extension (http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/HowToUseCQ5AsMavenRepository.html) to allow our CQ instance to act like a Maven repository.  This allows us to export the CQ JARs so we can then reference them as dependencies in the Java projects we create whenever we may need to use some of the classes available via CQ itself.

Once we set up the project dependencies, then we were able to write code--and corresponding unit tests--within the Intellij IDE.  We were able to run the tests within the IDE, allowing developers to remain in context and work on the code that will run in CQ just like they work on any Java code (including things like running tests in debug mode or with code coverage, running single tests, running all tests in a class, using keyboard shortcuts to kick off tests, etc.).  For us this approach had many advantages over the browser-based Sling test runner, so I recommend this approach.

Some potential considerations:

- Exporting from CQ as a Maven repo may not be the best performance--you may want to add things to your own Maven repo for faster access
- You may want to script some of the steps so adding project dependencies is not a manual process, but rather is something done via an automated process
- You could even export *all* CQ JARs--or add some scripting to parse out and repackage only the public classes--and make any CQ class available to your Java projects

Comment: The Apache Sling testing tools docs at http://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/sling-testing-tools.html point to an example (OsgiAwareTest) that shows how to write tests that run server-side in a Sling instance (which CQ is). See also  "testing Sling applications" at http://sling.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-how-tos/testing-sling-based-applications.html which gives a broader picture on the possible "levels" of testing.