# Unit testing AEM 6.1 and mocking sling, Jcr and Osgi

Tags: java, unit-testing, aem

**background**

Hi,

So I'm recently started at a company using AEM 6.1 and I'm also a junior developer.

When I pair with my buddy(senior developer) he generally drives. But doesn't write unit tests, this bugs me. He has explained that it's difficult to unit test AEM.

Our project makes use of http sling requests and responses, the Osgi framework and a large Jcr repository, jsps, servlets and database connections. We use all sorts of design patterns, create adapter classes ... And so on.

**Questions**

Why is it difficult to create unit tests for AEM, when there are mocking frameworks for sling, Osgi and Jcr?

How can I learn to unit test AEM 6.1?

**moving forward...**

I'm looking for resources to be able to create unit tests for AEM? If possible please can you link below any resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I felt the same way when I first began developing in AEM.  Over time I pushed to change that for my company, and now we have an environment where we unit test our AEM code.

Why is it difficult to test AEM code?  I think the main reasons boil down to 2 points:

1. Many Adobe examples come in the form of JSPs with inline Java code (scriptlets).  Scriptlet code is not testable, nor is it reusable.  I think one reason you see this so much from Adobe is that the product allows developers to "overlay" base functionality.  Built-in code runs under "libs," but developers can copy code in libs and place it in "apps" and then change it--and those changes will take effect in place of the existing code.  With JSPs that contain scriptlets, it is easy to substitute code like this because you can get the markup along with the Java code and still change it.  But if that Java code was in some other library, how could you replace it?  While it would be possible, it would be much more difficult.  So I think Adobe has a lot of sample code that shows Java code in scriptlets.  But this is bad practice, regardless of the reasons for it.  You can't do that if you want to unit test.  So don't allow it.  Require developers to put code in .java classes and include it via tags (or other similar mechanisms).  Then you can unit test the code--and more easily reuse it.
2. Most code you write for AEM will need to interact with the respository that AEM uses.  So you inevitably have dependencies to code/packages that are part of the base AEM installation.  When you try to write your own .java classes, you quickly find that unless you have these same dependencies on the classpath for your IDE, things won't compile.  For older AEM versions, there was no vendor-provided way to get these to my knowledge.  But recent versions have it--an "Uber" .jar.  I think dependency issues deter developers.  And they revert to scriptlets in JSPs for their Java code.  If you want to unit test your AEM code, you'll have to extract all the dependencies you have on AEM-provided code and make it part of your project in the IDE.  That is not trivial work, but it is prerequisite to being able to develop efficiently and test in a normal way in an IDE and continuous integration build project like you would in other Java projects.

We solved #2 by making a "container" .jar which contains all the .jar files from our AEM instance that we require to compile and unit test Java code. But recent AEM releases provide this in the Uber .jar, which makes this task much easier.  We also use Mockito for unit testing Java code.  It allows easy and powerful mocking of the Sling and AEM classes we depend on.  We use it all the time.  We occasionally also use PowerMockito for some mocking.

Beyond that, is it no more difficult to test Java code meant for use in AEM than it is to test any other Java code.  We also added JavaScript unit testing support using Karma and Jasmine--so the same thing applies to client side code.

Here are some resources that may help:

- https://github.com/justinedelson/aem-uberjar-demo
- https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/dev-tools/ht-projects-maven.html
- [AEM 6.1 Maven Dependency Resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675700/aem-6-1-maven-dependency-resolution)
- http://www.wemblog.com/2014/07/how-to-include-all-cq-dependencies-in.html
- http://blogs.adobe.com/cqpost/2012/03/19/unit-testing-in-adobedaycq5/
- [CQ - Writing Server-side JUnit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545248/cq-writing-server-side-junit-tests)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on code, one code you can easy cover with tests when other not. It's a big pain to support unit-tests for such "not testable" code (code which was created w/o tests in mind).

Here you can find libraries for Unit-tests [link](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development.html#testing-sling-based-applications) with examples.

Also you can test your code with smth like [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) (in many cases it's more easy to create mocks with Mockito rather than create [JCR fixture from JSON file](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/sling-mock.html#import-resource-data-from-json-file-in-classpath) in Sling mock library).

Answer (score 0):

One major issue is that the uber jar is obfuscated and thus it just contains the API interfaces and classes. As a result, you have to mock the AEM objects which is quite cumbersome. However, there is an UNobfuscated uber jar which is provided by Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

Writing tests for AEM shouldn't be hard, the Apache Sling community offers ways for testing on different levels and because AEM is based on Sling we can use the same tools.

Checkout the links below:

- Overview: https://sling.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-how-tos/testing-sling-based-applications.html
- Unit Testing: https://adapt.to/2016/en/schedule/unit-testing-with-sling-aem-mocks.html
- HTTP Testing: https://adapt.to/2016/en/schedule/sling-http-testing-framework.html
- Sling Mocks: https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/sling-mock.html